# Method to sort DataFrame's values

Tags: python, pandas, series

I don't understand this code:

```
d = {'col1': [5, 6,4, 1, 2, 9, 15, 11]}


df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.head(10)

df['col1'] = df.sort_values('col1')['col1']

print(df.sort_values('col1')['col1'])
```

This is what is printed:

```
3     1
4     2
2     4
0     5
1     6
5     9
7    11
6    15
```

My df doesn't change at all.
Why does this code: `df.sort_values('col1')['col1']` do not arrange my dataframe?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If want assign back sorted column is necessary convert output to numpy array for prevent index alignment - it means if use only `df.sort_values('col1')['col1']` it sorting correctly, index order is changed, but in assign step is change order like original, so no change in order of values.

```
df['col1'] = df.sort_values('col1')['col1'].to_numpy()
```

If default index another idea is create default index (same like original), so alignment asign by new index values:

```
df['col1'] = df.sort_values('col1')['col1'].reset_index(drop=True)
```

If want sort by `col1` column:

```
df = df.sort_values('col1')
```

Comment: Thanks! but could you explain me why it did not work?